# Replace char with a string or another char

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, format

Suppose I have an array of chars, just like this:

```
abc def ghi jkl ...
```

where words are separated **just** by spaces.

My goal is to replace all the existing spaces with some other strings (chars) I wish. For example:

```
abcMNPdefQRTghiXYZjkl
```

I thought about creating a function named **replace** that may do the following:

```
void replace(char *str, int pos, char *rep)
{
    //get length of rep
    //pos = position of the blank which i want to replace with rep
    //code to do the replacement
}
```

My initial idea was to shift right the elements of **str** by`strlen(rep)`and then **insert** rep.

Is the idea any good or is there any other better method?

Comment: `rep` is going to be "length" 1, byte size 1

Comment: Yes, it should've said `char *rep`. I've corrected it.

Comment: I would start by using a language with string handling. But if you're stuck with C, it would probably be much faster to allocate a big space for a new string, copy a character at a time from the old string to the new, inserting the extras at that time, then copy the newly created string to its final home. Trying to "insert" live into a string my moving bytes around is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//replace specified chunks in a string (size-independent, just remember about memory)
void replcnks(char *str, char *cnk1, char *cnk2)
{
    char *pos;
    int clen1 = strlen(cnk1), clen2 = strlen(cnk2);
    while(pos = strstr(str, cnk1))
    {
        memmove(pos + clen2, pos + clen1, strlen(pos) - clen1 + 1);
        memcpy(pos, cnk2, clen2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way - just as unsafe as Michal.z's version assuming pos is the zero based position:

```
void replace(char *str, int pos, char *rep)
{
    char *tmp=strdup(&str[pos+1]);
    strcat(&str[pos], rep);
    strcat(str, tmp);
    free(tmp);    
}
```

str has to have enough space to accommodate strlen(rep) more characters, or the code will fail.  A safer version would have to total space available so you could check and not insert something too large. Or malloc a completely new string, and return the new string.